"No one calls my husband a name." VS "No one can call my husband a name."
"No one calls my husband a name."
If I saw this sentence, I would think the sentence is a simple present tense, which is stating a fact, like "No one lives in this part of the world."
However, it actually means "No one CAN call my husband a name./No one has the power to call my husband a name.", because the sentence is said in a context where a wife tries to protect her husband from a mother-in-law who called him "Wuss."
So, I wonder is it common to use the simple present structure "No one calls ...." instead of the ability structure "No one can call ...." when you are actually referring to an ability/power/authoriation etc. rather than a fact?

Yes, very common.  The construction is often  a warning, or threat.

Nobody sets foot on my property without my permission!

It would be said to a trespasser. The practical meaning is something like "I don't allow it to happen, and if it does, there could well be unpleasant consequences."

I understand. This structure ("Nobody sets foot ......") reminds me of the imperative structure, which is used to tell someone to do or not to something. For example, in movies sometimes we hear "Nobody move!". This is also warning or a threat, but this is not in simple present structure. So, can we say "Nobody SET foot ....!" and "Nobody SETS foot ..." can both be used as a warning?

The command is different from the statement.  The command is pre-emptive.  The statement occurs after-the-fact.  If you say Nobody talks to me that way! it's because somebody has just talked to you that way.   So it means "Nobody talks to me that way (and gets away with it)."

ahhh I see now. Very good explanation. Thanks.
